# Can you spot the error in this excel function?

Tags: microsoft-excel

A user's come to me asking why this function isn't doing what he expects it to do.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F7, "5", "0"), "4", "2"), "3", "3"), "2", "4"), "1", "5")
```

Can you work out what the user thinks it ought to do and why it's not working as expected?

Comment: We'd need to know what it is supposed to do, and what it actually does. I mean, it would be very helpful.

Comment: All the user was doing was taking a single number 1-5 and converting it to 0,2,3,4,5.
A little logic teaser for a Thursday afternoon!

Comment: -1 for asking questions that don't need answering. I'll happily help with solving people's problems, but this is not the place for quizzes for fun.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like the intention is to change some numbers in a cell so that 5 is replaced with 0, 4->2, 3->3, 2->4 and 1->5.

Problem is it does it in *single steps* so, after the 4s are changed to 2s, you later change all the 2s (including the one's that *were* 4s) in to 4s.

Example:

```
12345 //lets look at each step...
12340 // 5 -> 0
12320 // 4 -> 2
12320 // 3 -> 3  : why is this step used?
14340 // 2 -> 4  : changes the 4 that was changed above back again
54340 // 1 -> 5

54320 // expected result?
```

If you wish to stick with this method you need to change the 4s to something irrelevant (say "X") and then (*after* changing the 2s) change the Xs in to 2s.

Comment: Yup, that's the problem.
My solution was to create a look up table elsewhere in the document and use vlookup.
Had me flummoxed for a little while until I broke it down like you did!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easier way (if you're only changing single-digit numbers):

```
=IF(6-F7=1,0,6-F7)
```

Comment: This only works if it is a single digit number.

Comment: @Dan, I was thinking that was the user was doing, but see now he might have been doing this on larger numbers or text strings.  I'll edit in the constraint.